# union streaming data into a global static rdd and use the static rdd periodicity

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

the pseudo code :

```
object myApp { 
  var myStaticRDD: RDD[Int] 
  def main() { 
    ...  //init streaming context, and get two DStream (streamA and streamB) from two hdfs path 

    //complex transformation using the two DStream 
    val new_stream = streamA.transformWith(StreamB, (a, b, t) => { 
        a.join(b).map(...) 
      } 
    ) 

    //join the new_stream's rdd with myStaticRDD 
    new_stream.foreachRDD(rdd => 
      myStaticRDD = myStaticRDD.union(cur_stream) 
    ) 


    // do complex model training every two hours. 
    if (hour is 0, 2, 4, 6...) { 
       model_training(myStaticRDD)   //will take 1 hour 
    } 
  } 
}
```

I don't know how to write the code to realize training model every two hours using that moment's myStaticRDD.

And when the model-training is running, the streaming task could also run normally simultaneously and the streamA, streamB, new_stream, myStaticRDD could be updated in real-time. maybe I need to use multi-thread?

one possible solution maybe:

```
   object myApp { 
      var myStaticRDD: RDD[Int] 
      def main() { 
        ...  //init streaming context, and get two DStream (streamA and streamB) from two hdfs path 

        //complex transformation using the two DStream 
        val new_stream = streamA.transformWith(StreamB, (a, b, t) => { 
            a.join(b).map(...) 
          } 
        ) 

        //join the new_stream's rdd with myStaticRDD 
        new_stream.foreachRDD(rdd => 
          myStaticRDD = myStaticRDD.union(cur_stream) 
        // do complex model training every two hours. 
          if (hour is 0, 2, 4, 6...) { 
             val tmp_rdd = myStaticRDD 
             new Thread(model_training(tmp_rdd))   //start a child-thread to train the model...
          } 
        ) 


      } 
    }
```

Comment: I would split that job in the streaming that stores data somewhere and a scheduled batch job each x hours that computes those models.